# ggplot2: forcing grid spacing to be identical on x and y axis without manually setting limits

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting PCA data and by default, ggplot2 uses different grid spacing on the X and Y axis (e.g. each tick on the x axis = 10, but each tick on the y axis = 5).  I need to plot a wide range of data, so I do not want to set manual limits for the y and x axes each time.

I tried the [`coord_fixed()` solution in this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13446470), but it does not work well, and it still only makes the grid square, and does not force the scale of the grid to be the same on x and y.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Is the problem that the range of the axes do not align, or that the ticks are different?

Comment: You can pass a function to the `break` and `label` arguments.

Comment: it's fine if the range of the axes is different, however, the x and y axes are being scaled differently, so the data are being plotted in a distorted/misrepresented way, since the units for PC1 and PC2 should be directly comparable.

Comment: @James, please see my edit as an example on how to include a minimal working example for the question. It is good practise as it makes it easier to help.

Comment: When the legend is present, the coord_fixed() solution does not work well, and it still only makes the grid square, and does not force the scale of the grid to be the same on x and y.

Comment: @Jaap this is not a duplicate. This question is distinct (see above).

Comment: Expected output is not clear. Do we want x and y range to be same, [like 0 to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468280/scale-a-series-between-two-points)? Or do we want plot to be square? (`ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) + geom_point() + theme(aspect.ratio=1)`) Or do we want output plot as a file, square? (`ggsave(width = 500, height = 500)`) ?

Comment: Could you explain what is different?

Comment: All I want to do is make the SCALE equivalent on the X and Y axes, while having different y and x limits. This means each tick on x and y is equally spaced and represents the same scale. I do not understand why this is so difficult in R. For example, y axis range is 0 to 20, x axis range is -50 to 50, but in both axes each tick is drawn in an interval of 10. I do not want to manually specify the ranges of 0-20, -50-50.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [coord_equal](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_fixed.html):

```
+ coord_equal(ratio = 1)
```