# Accessing vector of axis ticks for an existing plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to get the vector of values for axis ticks in an existing plot in ggplot. I know that a ggplot object is a list with 9 elements and I was wondering if somehow I could extract the values for the axis ticks from that list. For example if I produce this toy example:

```
library(ggplot2)
g=ggplot(data=mtcars,aes(hp,mpg))+geom_point()
```

[image]
What I want are the vectors

```
 c(100,200,300)
 c(10,15,20,25,30,35)
```

for x ticks and y ticks respectively w

Is there a way to to this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those values can be found in

```
ggbld <- ggplot_build(g)
ggbld$panel$ranges[[1]]$x.major_source
#[1] 100 200 300
```

and

```
ggbld$panel$ranges[[1]]$y.major_source
#[1] 10 15 20 25 30 35
```

They can also be found stored as characters here:

```
ggbld$panel$ranges[[1]]$x.labels
#[1] "100" "200" "300"
ggbld$panel$ranges[[1]]$y.labels
#[1] "10" "15" "20" "25" "30" "35"
```

#### Update:

The above doesn't work with ggplot2_3.0.0, but that information can be still be found using:

```
ggbld <- ggplot_build(g)
ggbld$layout$coord$labels(ggbld$layout$panel_params)[[1]]$x.major_source
ggbld$layout$coord$labels(ggbld$layout$panel_params)[[1]]$x.labels
```

Comment: Wow,thank you for a quick and a great response. So the ggplot_build function both plots the plot and returns a list of info about the plot?

Comment: `ggplot_build` according to its help page: "...is the powerhouse that converts the plot specification into something that's ready to be rendered on screen."  It doesn't plot the data, but it does return a list of info about the plot object.

Comment: @Jota Apparently, the ggplot structure has changed somewhat. To get the panel ranges, I had to use `ggplot_build(g)$layout$panel_ranges[[1]]$x.major_source`. The above commands return NULL.

Comment: This doesn't work for ggplot2_3.0.0 anymore, any ideas?

Comment: @zx8754 Hm, maybe there's a better way, but you can use `ggplot_build(g)$layout$coord$labels(ggplot_build(g)$layout$panel_params)[[1]]$x.major_source` or `ggplot_build(g)$layout$coord$labels(ggplot_build(g)$layout$panel_params)[[1]]$x.labels`

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on the comments on @Jota's answer, the methods mentioned appear to have changed. Using one of the following no longer appears to work:

```
ggplot_build(g)$layout$panel_ranges[[1]]$x.major_source
ggbld <- ggplot_build(g)
ggbld$layout$coord$labels(ggbld$layout$panel_params)[[1]]$x.labels
ggbld$layout$coord$labels(ggbld$layout$panel_params)[[1]]$x.major_source
```

Using of `ggplot2` version `3.5.5`, I can extract the major tick marks, as per the original question, with:

```
(g1 <- ggplot_build(g)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x$breaks)
```

giving

```
[1]  NA 100 200 300  NA
```

which we can subset with `g1[which(!is.na(g1))]`.

In case of interest, the *minor* tick marks (visible as thin lines on the plot but not labelled on the axis) can be extracted with:

```
ggplot_build(g)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x$minor_breaks
```

giving

```
[1]  50 100 150 200 250 300
```