# How can I determine the x and y coordinates of the corners in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the code:

```
xbreaks <- c(100, 200, 300)
ybreaks <- c(2, 3, 4, 5)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, wt)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=xbreaks) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=ybreaks) +
  geom_point()
```

Here is the plot:

[image]

How can I find the X and Y values corresponding to the bottom left-hand corner (which I've marked with a green dot)? I guess that they are approximately (40, 1.40), but can I ask R for the exact values?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705345/how-can-i-extract-plot-axes-ranges-for-a-ggplot2-object/35372274#answer-40304848

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can!  Try this:

```
g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, wt)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=xbreaks) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=ybreaks) +
  geom_point()

b <- ggplot_build(g)
b$layout$panel_ranges[[1]]$x.range

[1]  37.85 349.15
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I can see that ggplot_build() will be useful to know about.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the coordinates or do you want to plot something there? To plot something there, you can use `-Inf` (or `Inf` for the opposite site) as x and y coordinates:

```r
library(ggplot2)
xbreaks <- c(100, 200, 300)
ybreaks <- c(2, 3, 4, 5)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, wt)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=xbreaks) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=ybreaks) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(aes(x = -Inf, y = -Inf), color = "blue", inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]

Notice the blue dot in the lower left corner. It is clipped by default, but you can switch off clipping to show the entire dot:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, wt)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=xbreaks) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=ybreaks) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(aes(x = -Inf, y = -Inf), color = "blue", inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-29 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. It's nice that -Inf stops at the edge of the plot!

Answer (score 1):

Note that as of ggplot2 2.2.1.9000, the parameter within `layout` is changed from `panel_ranges` but `panel_params`.

The current ggplot (stable) 2.2.1 version uses `layout$panel_ranges` the upstream version 2.2.1.9000 on [Github](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2) now uses `layout$panel_params`

Example Code and console output below:

### Updated ggplot2

```
require("devtools")
devtools::install_git("git@github.com:tidyverse/ggplot2.git")

data(mtcars)
xbreaks <- c(100, 200, 300)
ybreaks <- c(2, 3, 4, 5)
g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, wt)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=xbreaks) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=ybreaks) +
  geom_point()

b <- ggplot_build(g)
b$layout$panel_ranges[[1]]$x.range


g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, wt)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=xbreaks) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=ybreaks) +
  geom_point()

b <- ggplot_build(g)
b$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x.range
```

### Console Output:

```
> require("devtools")
Loading required package: devtools
> devtools::install_git("git@github.com:tidyverse/ggplot2.git")
Downloading git repo git@github.com:tidyverse/ggplot2.git
Installing ggplot2
'/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.5.0_1/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save  \
  --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  '/private/var/folders/md/03gdc4c14z18kbqwpfh4jdfc0000gp/T/RtmpwOWMNj/filee8386283a116'  \
  --library='/usr/local/lib/R/3.5/site-library' --install-tests 

* installing *source* package ‘ggplot2’ ...
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** tests
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (ggplot2)
Reloading installed ggplot2
> data(mtcars)
> xbreaks <- c(100, 200, 300)
> ybreaks <- c(2, 3, 4, 5)
> g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, wt)) +
+   scale_x_continuous(breaks=xbreaks) +
+   scale_y_continuous(breaks=ybreaks) +
+   geom_point()
> b <- ggplot_build(g)
> b$layout$panel_ranges[[1]]$x.range
NULL
> g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, wt)) +
+   scale_x_continuous(breaks=xbreaks) +
+   scale_y_continuous(breaks=ybreaks) +
+   geom_point()
> b <- ggplot_build(g)
> b$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x.range
[1]  37.85 349.15
```