# set axes limits in patchwork when combining ggplot2 objects

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

When combining `ggplot2` objects using [patchwork](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/index.html) I would like to be able to have an option that I could easily set an option for all the plots to have the same x-axis and/or y-axis range.

**reprex:**

```r
library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

p1 <- mtcars %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(mpg, disp)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 1')

p2 <- mtcars %>% 
  filter(disp < 300) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(mpg, disp)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 2')

p1 + p2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**expected result setting it to both axes having the same range across both plots:**

```r
library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

p1 <- mtcars %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(mpg, disp)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 1')

p2 <- mtcars %>% 
  filter(disp < 300) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(mpg, disp)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 2') +
  xlim(ggplot_build(p1)$layout$panel_scales_x[[1]]$range$range) +
  ylim(ggplot_build(p1)$layout$panel_scales_y[[1]]$range$range)

p1 + p2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can I ask what's wrong with what you're already doing? What would a solution look like? Would you want some function like `f(p1 + p2)` that set the axes equally?

Comment: yeah I was expecting to be able to have an option directly in the pkg to do that, since my real example is much more complex.. although, I have found the solution now, I will post the answer soon

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Alright, I am sorry for answering my own question, but I just found the solution..

This can be nicely achieved by using the `&`, which applies the function to all the plots in the patchwork object.

**1) reprex:**

```r
library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

p1 <- mtcars %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(mpg, disp)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 1')

p2 <- mtcars %>% 
  filter(disp < 300) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(mpg, disp)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 2')

p_combined <- p1 + p2

p_combined
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**2) Get the min and max values from the ranges:**

```r
p_ranges_x <- c(ggplot_build(p_combined[[1]])$layout$panel_scales_x[[1]]$range$range,
  ggplot_build(p_combined[[2]])$layout$panel_scales_x[[1]]$range$range)

p_ranges_y <- c(ggplot_build(p_combined[[1]])$layout$panel_scales_y[[1]]$range$range,
                ggplot_build(p_combined[[2]])$layout$panel_scales_y[[1]]$range$range)
```

**3) Apply these ranges to the patchwork object:**

```r
p_combined & 
  xlim(min(p_ranges_x), max(p_ranges_x)) & 
  ylim(min(p_ranges_y), max(p_ranges_y))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Here is a slight modification make the above operation into a function:

```
apply_consistent_y_lims <- function(this_plot){
    num_plots <- length(this_plot$layers)
    y_lims <- lapply(1:num_plots, function(x) ggplot_build(this_plot[[x]])$layout$panel_scales_y[[1]]$range$range)
    min_y <- min(unlist(y_lims))
    max_y <- max(unlist(y_lims))
    this_plot & ylim(min_y, max_y)
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution, beware however: it cuts of data in the right plot, when it has data with higher y values than the left plot, to see this try apply_consistent_y_lims(p2+p1)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705345/how-can-i-extract-plot-axes-ranges-for-a-ggplot2-object

Comment: @MartineJ I'm not seeing that problem, function seems to work just fine for me, so far.

Comment: strange, for me it still ( in the mean while other RStudio, R and packages versions)  removes 11 rows containing missing values (geom_point), when i run apply_consistent_y_lims(p2+p1).