# How to automatically set the scale for x-axis to be equal for all subplots in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to merge three subplots in with ggplot2. I know I can use **gridspec_kw** in matplotlib in python. Is there any similar way in ggplot2? For example, the range of x-axis of the plot 1 is (0,5), and the width of its x-axis is 5 cm. The range of x-axis of the plot 2 is (0,10), and the width of its x-axis must be 10 cm.

I use **grid.arrange(plot1, plot2,plot3, ncol=3)** to merge three subplots. How can I set the scale for x-axis to be equal for all subplots?

Comment: I don't think `grid.*` makes this easy, you may want to look at `patchwork` and https://stackoverflow.com/q/60016390/3358272

Comment: Have you considered `facet_grid()` with free x-axes and free `space`?

Answer (score 2):

You could try {patchwork} package, which excels at doing these jobs. For your jobs this could work:

```r
library(patchwork)
plot1 + plot2 + plot_layout(widths = c(1, 2))
```

See [here](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/layout.html) for more details.