# ggplot2 + patchwork: alignment of y-axis

Tags: ggplot2, patchwork

i made 3 plots with ggplot2 and arranged it with patchwork. Since one of the plots only has positive values, one only negative and the third both positive and negative values, i have trouble to align the y-axis (y=0) for all three plots at the same height. Is there a way to do this via patchwork, or do i have to change the whole data preparation?

Thanks a lot for any help!

This is my code:

```
plot_1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_bar(
    data = data_p1, 
    aes(fill = SF, y = Anzahl, x = year), 
    position = 'stack', stat = 'identity') +
  labs(
    title = "title 1",
    x = "",
    y = "",
    fill = ""  
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, big.mark = ".")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = farben) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 11, face = "bold"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8),
  ) 

plot_2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_bar(
    data = data_p2_1, 
    aes(fill = SF, y = Anzahl, x = year), 
    position = 'stack', stat = 'identity') +
  labs(
    title = "",
    x = "",
    y = "",
    fill = ""  
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, big.mark = ".")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = farben) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 11, face = "bold"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8)
  ) +
  geom_bar(
    data = data_p2_2, 
    aes(fill = SF, y = Anzahl*-1, x = year), 
    position = 'stack', stat = 'identity') +
  labs(
    title = "title 2",
    x = "",
    y = "",
    fill = ""  
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, big.mark = ".")) + 
  # scale_fill_manual(values = farben) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 11, face = "bold"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8)
  ) 

plot_3 <- ggplot() +
geom_bar(
  data = data_p3, 
  aes(fill = SF, y = Anzahl*-1, x = year), 
  position = 'stack', stat = 'identity') +
  labs(
    title = "title 3",
    x = "",
    y = "",
    fill = ""  
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, big.mark = ".")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = farben) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 11, face = "bold"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8)
  )

patchwork <- plot_1 + plot_2 + plot_3
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6q4k.png)

Comment: I would suggest that perhaps you add a constant `ylim` to the three plots and see if that helps it line up. I can't test this/reproduce your problem as I don't have your data - do consider sharing a sample of your data or some randomly generated values which repeat the problem you're having and we can try to give a fuller answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60018428/10744082), using `& ylim()` should give multiple aligned plots:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

data_a <- tibble(a = letters[1:5],
                 b = sample(20:100, 5))


p1 <- data_a |> 
  ggplot(aes(a, b)) + 
  geom_col()

p2 <- data_a |> 
  ggplot(aes(a, b * -1)) +
  geom_col()


p1 + p2 & ylim(-100, 100)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Andy, thank you very much. This helped me a lot!