# Get axis limits from ggplot object

Tags: r, ggplot2

Sometimes I will make two plots that are similair, but have different data.
As such, the X- and Y-axis will have different ranges.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: magrittr
df1 <- data.frame(x=runif(10)*2,y = runif(10)*2)
df2 <- data.frame(x=runif(10)*3,y = runif(10)*1)
p1 <- qplot(x = x, y = y, data = df1, geom = "line")
p2 <- qplot(x = x, y = y, data = df2, geom = "line")

ggarrange(p1,p2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This can manually be overcome by explicitly stating a range with `xlim` and `ylim`, but this is both tiresome and could lead to some data being outside of the specified range if one is not careful.

An ideal solution would be to dynamically obtain the limits from the `p1`, and if these are larger than those of `p2`, use those instead for `p2`. For example `p2 + xlim(getLimits(p1))`.

Is something like this supported?

EDIT:
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705345/how-can-i-extract-plot-axes-ranges-for-a-ggplot2-object) was suggested, but the answer applies to an older version of `ggplot2`. Additionally, the supported `p1$coordinates$limits` only return the *manually specified* limits, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: I took a look at it, but I wasn't able to get the limits using either the `coordinates$limits` object, or the other that were proposed. It seems like it was an older version of `ggplot2`. Additionally, `p1$coordinates$limits` only return the limits that were specified with `xlim` etc.

Comment: [The second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35372274/8366499) in that duplicate question includes the newer `layer_scales` function while the 3rd discussed the `ggplot_build` option, both of which should do what you want to do, I think

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ggplot now has `layer_***` convenience functions for extracting information from ggplots. In this case you can use the `layer_scales` function:

```
layer_scales(p1)$y$get_limits()

[1] 0.1499588 1.9527970
```

So you could do something like:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)
library(ggpubr)
theme_set(theme_bw())

set.seed(2)
df1 <- data.frame(x=runif(10)*2,y = runif(10)*2)
df2 <- data.frame(x=runif(10)*3,y = runif(10)*1)
p1 <- qplot(x = x, y = y, data = df1, geom = "line")
p2 <- qplot(x = x, y = y, data = df2, geom = "line")

fnc = function(...) {
  
  p = list(...)
  
  yr = map(p, ~layer_scales(.x)$y$get_limits()) %>% 
    unlist %>% range
  
  xr = map(p, ~layer_scales(.x)$x$get_limits()) %>% 
    unlist %>% range
  
  p %>% map(~.x + xlim(xr) + ylim(yr))
}

wrap_plots(fnc(p1, p2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just draw one graph instead of two:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# 1. create datasets
df1 <- data.frame(x=runif(10)*2, y = runif(10)*2)
df2 <- data.frame(x=runif(10)*3, y = runif(10)*1)


# 2. union datasets and plot
df1 %>% 
  mutate(dataset_name = "Dataframe #1") %>% 
  bind_rows(df2 %>% mutate(dataset_name = "Dataframe #2")) %>% 

  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_grid(~ dataset_name)
```

[image]

Comment: This assumes the data is bindable, e.g. no unique columns (which could be filtered out, but certainly complicates the process).

Comment: Why? `dplyr::bind_rows` doesn't require that merged dateframes contain the same number or names of columns.

Comment: I stand corrected - I thought it was little but a wrapper for `rbind`, but I tested it and it seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for `ggplot_build()`? The output of that function includes a panel object which contains axis limits. You can read more about it [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/3.3.2/topics/ggplot_build). This is to get the panel object:

```r
panel1 <- ggplot_build(p1)$panel
panel2 <- ggplot_build(p2)$panel
```

And then you can extract the ranges for x and y from there. The exact specifics depends on your installation version of *ggplot2*. Hope this helps.