# Align time series ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to align the x axes on these plots, I think if I could change the width so they had the same width would work but I haven't been able to do it.
[image: misaligned plots]

my data looks like this:

```
> x<-as.data.frame(table(casosbog$fis))
> dput(x[1:10,c('Var1','Freq')])
structure(list(Var1 = structure(1:10, .Label = c("2020-02-27", 
"2020-02-28", "2020-03-01", "2020-03-04", "2020-03-05", "2020-03-06", 
"2020-03-07", "2020-03-08", "2020-03-09", "2020-03-10", "2020-03-11", 
"2020-03-12", "2020-03-13", "2020-03-14", "2020-03-15", "2020-03-16", 
"2020-03-17", "2020-03-18", "2020-03-19", "2020-03-20", "2020-03-21", 
"2020-03-22", "2020-03-23", "2020-03-24", "2020-03-25", "2020-03-26", 
"2020-03-27", "2020-03-28", "2020-03-29", "2020-03-30", "2020-03-31", 
"2020-04-01", "2020-04-02", "2020-04-03", "2020-04-04", "2020-04-05", 
"2020-04-06", "2020-04-07", "2020-04-08", "2020-04-09", "2020-04-10", 
"2020-04-11", "2020-04-12", "2020-04-13", "2020-04-14", "2020-04-15", 
"2020-04-16", "2020-04-17", "2020-04-18", "2020-04-19", "2020-04-20", 
"2020-04-21", "2020-04-22", "2020-04-23", "2020-04-24", "2020-04-25", 
"2020-04-26", "2020-04-27", "2020-04-28", "2020-04-29", "2020-04-30", 
"2020-05-01", "2020-05-02", "2020-05-03", "2020-05-04", "2020-05-05", 
"2020-05-06", "2020-05-07", "2020-05-08", "2020-05-09", "2020-05-10", 
"2020-05-11", "2020-05-12", "2020-05-13", "2020-05-14", "2020-05-15", 
"2020-05-16", "2020-05-17", "2020-05-18", "2020-05-19", "2020-05-20", 
"2020-05-21", "2020-05-22", "2020-05-23", "2020-05-24", "2020-05-25", 
"2020-05-26", "2020-05-27", "2020-05-28", "2020-05-29", "2020-05-30", 
"2020-05-31", "2020-06-01", "2020-06-02", "2020-06-03", "2020-06-04", 
"2020-06-05", "2020-06-06", "2020-06-07", "2020-06-08", "2020-06-09", 
"2020-06-10", "2020-06-11", "2020-06-12", "2020-06-13", "2020-06-14", 
"2020-06-15", "2020-06-16", "2020-06-17", "2020-06-18", "2020-06-19", 
"2020-06-20", "2020-06-21", "2020-06-22", "2020-06-23", "2020-06-24", 
"2020-06-25", "2020-06-26", "2020-06-27", "2020-06-28", "2020-06-29", 
"2020-06-30", "2020-07-01", "2020-07-02", "2020-07-03", "2020-07-04", 
"2020-07-05", "2020-07-06", "2020-07-07", "2020-07-08", "2020-07-09", 
"2020-07-10", "2020-07-11", "2020-07-12", "2020-07-13", "2020-07-14", 
"2020-07-15", "2020-07-16", "2020-07-17", "2020-07-18", "2020-07-19", 
"2020-07-20", "2020-07-21", "2020-07-22", "2020-07-23", "2020-07-24", 
"2020-07-25", "2020-07-26", "2020-07-27", "2020-07-28", "2020-07-29", 
"2020-07-30", "2020-07-31", "2020-08-01", "2020-08-02", "2020-08-03", 
"2020-08-04", "2020-08-05", "2020-08-06", "2020-08-07", "2020-08-08", 
"2020-08-09", "2020-08-10", "2020-08-11", "2020-08-12", "2020-08-13", 
"2020-08-14", "2020-08-15", "2020-08-16", "2020-08-17", "2020-08-18", 
"2020-08-19", "2020-08-20", "2020-08-21", "2020-08-22", "2020-08-23", 
"2020-08-24", "2020-08-25", "2020-08-26", "2020-08-27", "2020-08-28", 
"2020-08-29", "2020-08-30", "2020-08-31", "2020-09-01", "2020-09-02", 
"2020-09-03", "2020-09-04", "2020-09-05", "2020-09-06", "2020-09-07", 
"2020-09-08", "2020-09-09", "2020-09-10", "2020-09-11", "2020-09-12", 
"2020-09-13", "2020-09-14", "2020-09-15", "2020-09-16", "2020-09-17"
), class = "factor"), Freq = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 5L, 
5L, 11L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

and

```
> movilcolbog[1:10,c('date','MovilidadProm')]
         date MovilidadProm
1  2020-02-15     7.0000000
2  2020-02-16     4.6666667
3  2020-02-17     5.3333333
4  2020-02-18     7.5000000
5  2020-02-19     2.6666667
6  2020-02-20    -0.3333333
7  2020-02-21     5.0000000
8  2020-02-22     1.8333333
9  2020-02-23    -7.3333333
10 2020-02-24     3.5000000
```

as you can see both dataframes have different starting dates and dates frequencies, the rest of the code is as follows

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

plot2<-ggplot(movilcolbaq,aes(date,MovilidadProm))+geom_line(aes(color="Mov.  BAQ"),size=1)+
  geom_line(data=movilcolbog,aes(color="Mov.  BOG"),size=1)+
  labs(color="Legend text")+
labs(title='Movilidad promedio (con respecto a enero-febrero) BOG, BAQ',x='',y='Cambio de movilidad en %')+
      theme(legend.title=element_blank())

plot1<-ggplot(casosbog,aes(x=fis,fill='Casos Bog'))+geom_bar()+
geom_bar(data=casosbar,aes(x=fis,fill='Casos Bar'),alpha=0.7)+
  scale_colour_manual("", values = c("Casos Bog"="red", "Casos Baq"="blue"))+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+labs(x='Fecha de inicio de síntomas',
                                            y='Casos',
                                            title='Fecha de inicio síntomas BAQ vs BOG vs MED',
                                           subtitle='Fuentes: INS y www.google.com/covid19/mobility/')

grid.arrange(plot1,plot2)
```

I've tried changing the xlim but it hasn't worked

Comment: Try `facet_wrap`.  Post a [mcve] if you would like more specific help - it's not possible to reproduce your results with the code you have posted.

Comment: `facet_wrap` would do it, but it would be more work than just using `coord_cartesian()` for both plots

Comment: @andrew_reece I think it's more understandable now

Comment: Yes, that's better - but please post `dput` output so it's easy to copy and paste.  E.g. `dput(x[1:10,c('Var1','Freq')])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can become quite tedious to align plots with `ggplot2` and it can seem that alot of manual work is necessary. But using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35372274/10782538) and assuming you are using *`ggplot2>=3.1.0`* we can actually achieve this very easily with `patchwork`.

The core of my solution is that the scales (and limits) of a plot can be extracted from any plot from the object returned by `layer_scales(ggplot)`. In this object we have the scales of each axis within the `x` and `y` fields which each contain a `range` object with a `range` field. In total we can extract the `x` axis of a plot using `layer_scales(ggplot)$x$range$range`. Below I'll use a dummy dataset to illustrate how we can achieve the alignment

```
# Setup
set.seed(1)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
d1 <- data.frame(y = rnorm(10), date = as.Date('2020-01-01') + months(1:10))
d2 <- data.frame(y = rnorm(10), date = as.Date('2020-03-01') + months(1:10))
p1 <- ggplot(d1, aes(y = y, x = date)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
p2 <- ggplot(d2, aes(y = y, x = date)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
# Solution
## Extract scales
scales <- lapply(list(p1, p2), layer_scales)

## Find range from layer_scales object. It is contained in obj$x$range$range
xlim <- map(scales,~ as.numeric(.x$x$range$range)) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  range()

## Add scales. Note that scales were numeric, so here I convert them back to dates.
## origin = '1970-01-01' is the standard origin for almost all programming languages.
p1 / p2 & coord_cartesian(xlim = as.Date(xlim, origin = '1970-01-01'))
```

[image: aligned-ggplot]
Note that in the code snippet above I used the patchwork `&` operator to apply the coord to each plot.

Comment: This is the right answer as I've already tried the patchwork package and didn't have any success, thanks!

Comment: Glad i could help. It also taught me a bit that I didn't already know before creating the answer. :-)

Comment: would it be possible to customise the x axis breaks, like show the first day of the month? I tried it on the plots using scale_x_date but it won't work @Oliver

Comment: Adding `& scale_x_date(breaks = as.Date('2020-02-01') + months(seq(0, 11, 3)))` to the plot above. works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `patchwork` as this package has the feature to align the labels in the multiple plots that are combined. You have multiple data sources so a `facet_wrap()` approach could not work. Also the data you shared is very small. As @andrew_reece said, next time share data with a considerable size. I have used the data you shared to create similar plots like those you included. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
#Code
plot2<-ggplot(movilcolbog,aes(date,MovilidadProm))+geom_line(aes(color="Mov.  BAQ"),size=1)+
  geom_line(data=movilcolbog,aes(color="Mov.  BOG"),size=1)+
  labs(color="Legend text")+labs(title='Movilidad promedio (con respecto a enero-febrero) BOG, BAQ',x='',y='Cambio de movilidad en %')+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())

plot1<-ggplot(x,aes(x=Var1,fill=Freq))+geom_bar()+
  # geom_bar(data=casosbar,aes(x=fis,fill='Casos Bar'),alpha=0.7)+
  scale_colour_manual("", values = c("Casos Bog"="red", "Casos Baq"="blue"))+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+labs(x='Fecha de inicio de síntomas',
                                           y='Casos',
                                           title='Fecha de inicio síntomas BAQ vs BOG vs MED',
                                           subtitle='Fuentes: INS y www.google.com/covid19/mobility/')
#Final plot
Fplot <- plot2/plot1
```

Output:

[image]

You can further tune up your axis labels and `patchwork` will align them. And as seen in plot even with different labels the package align those with are present at same level.

Some data used:

```
#Data 1
x <- structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(18319, 18320, 18322, 18325, 
18326, 18327, 18328, 18329, 18330, 18331), class = "Date"), Freq = c(1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 11L)), row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")

#Data 2
movilcolbog <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18307, 18308, 18309, 18310, 
18311, 18312, 18313, 18314, 18315, 18316), class = "Date"), MovilidadProm = c(7, 
4.6666667, 5.3333333, 7.5, 2.6666667, -0.3333333, 5, 1.8333333, 
-7.3333333, 3.5)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
```