# ggplot - how to draw rays?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot, It's easy to draw lines:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpp)

ggplot() + 
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = 0, slope = 2)) +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = 0, slope = 5)) + 
  geom_quadrant_lines()
```

[image]

But what if I want to draw rays, i.e. lines which extend to infinity only from one side?

I want my rays to start at the origin and extend into the 3rd quadrant.

One could use `geom_segment` to do something like this, but the problem is that I don't know the `xend` and `yend` parameters since the ray doesn't really end.

So how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

you could roll your own `geom_ray`:

```
geom_ray <- function(x = 0, y = 0, rho = 0, raylength = 1, ...){
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, y = y,
                   xend = raylength * cos(rho),
                   yend = raylength * sin(rho)
                   ),
               ...
               )
}
```

```
data.frame(a = 1, b = 1) |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_ray(rho = 0, col = 'blue') +
  geom_ray(rho = pi/4, col = 'red') +
  geom_ray(rho = pi/2, col = 'green')
```

[image: geom_ray]

Note that you still have to manually adjust the `raylength`s. (Couldn't figure out how query the axes ranges for a [`ggplot` object not yet built](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705345/how-can-i-extract-plot-axes-ranges-for-a-ggplot2-object).)

Comment: nice. the axis range in a continuous coordinate system are the limits +/- 5% of the range, see `?scale_x_continuous`

Comment: Thank you tjebo. What I'd like `geom_ray` to do, though, is to pick up the calculated axis ranges *during creation* of the object, i.e. while adding the layer (ideally not even from separately examining the incoming data).

Comment: This is not how ggplot works out the range though. It’s based on the data. I don’t see a big problem in calculating it beforehand

Answer (score 1):

Would it work to just make really long lines and pick whatever viewing window you want?

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = xe, yend = ye),
               data = data.frame(xe = -1E9, ye = -c(2, 5)*1E9)) +
  geom_quadrant_lines() +
  coord_equal(xlim = 0.05*c(-1,1), ylim = 0.05*c(-1,1))
```

[image]