# Automated procedure to draw ray in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

In R and `ggplot2`, it is easy to draw `lines` and `segment` but more difficult to draw rays. I am wondering if a solution exists to draw rays between two points; one defined as the origin (red point in the figure displayed by the code below) and the ray passing by a second point (black points in the figure displayed by the code below). Here is a piece of code I wrote for this:

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot)

set.seed(123)
n <- 4

dat <-
  data.frame(
  X = rnorm(n),
  Y = rnorm(n))

centroid <- 
  dat %>%
  dplyr::summarise(across(c(X,Y), mean))

ggplot(data = dat, aes(X,Y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = centroid, aes(X, Y), col = "red") +
  geom_segment(x = centroid$X, y = centroid$Y,
               xend = dat$X, yend = dat$Y)
```

A similar topic has been opened last year: [ggplot - how to draw rays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76142489/ggplot-how-to-draw-rays) but it does not fully match my concern since I want to avoid trigonometry and I want to automate this.

An help or suggestion or alternative solution is more than welcome.

Comment: *"want to avoid trigonometry"* ... you want no trigonometry to be used, or you just don't want to have to think about it? Trig is fairly relevant (required, even?) when you want to find coordinates given an origin and bearing or slope of a line.

Comment: It is a personal concern since I am terrible with trigonometry... Nothing else

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could write your own geom kind of like they do in the other question. Here's another possible solution

```
geom_ray <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL,
                        ...,
                     na.rm = FALSE,
                     show.legend = NA) {
  
  layer(
    data = data,
    mapping = mapping,
    stat = StatIdentity,
    geom = GeomRay,
    position = PositionIdentity,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = FALSE,
    params = rlang::list2(
      na.rm = na.rm,
      ...
    )
  )
}

GeomRay <- ggproto("GeomRay", Geom,
    draw_panel = function(data, panel_params, coord, lineend = "butt") {
      ranges <- coord$backtransform_range(panel_params)
      
      if (coord$clip == "on" && coord$is_linear()) {
        # Ensure the line extends well outside the panel to avoid visible line
        # ending for thick lines
        ranges$x <- ranges$x + c(-1, 1) * diff(ranges$x)
      }

      slope <- (data$towardy - data$y)/(data$towardx - data$x)
      intercept <- data$y - data$x*slope
      data$x    <- data$x
      data$y    <- data$y
      data$xend    <- ifelse(data$towardx > data$x, 
                             ranges$x[2],
                             ranges$x[1]
      )
      data$yend <- ifelse(data$towardx > data$x, 
                          ranges$x[2] * slope + intercept,
                          ranges$x[1] * slope + intercept
                          )
      
      GeomSegment$draw_panel(ggplot2:::unique0(data), panel_params, coord, lineend = lineend)
    },
    
    default_aes = aes(colour = "black", linewidth = 0.5, linetype = 1, alpha = NA),
    required_aes = c("x", "y", "towardx", "towardy"),
    
    draw_key = draw_key_abline,
    
    rename_size = TRUE,
    
    check_constant_aes = FALSE
)
```

This code was basically directly adapted from the `ggplot::geom_abline` code.

With this setup, the `x` and `y` are where you want the ray to start, and then `towardx` and `towardy` are the directions you want the ray to point. So with your data you would use it like

```
ggplot(data = dat, aes(X,Y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = centroid, aes(X, Y), col = "red") +
  geom_ray(x = centroid$X, y = centroid$Y,
               aes(towardx = X, towardy = Y))
```

which produces
[image]

Comment: double ++1 for writing a proper `Geom`!

Comment: Honestly ... I think this could easily be formalized as a ggplot2 extension, either by itself or in `ggh4x` or `ggforce` or several of the other extensions.

Comment: I probably should have switched `x,y,towardx,towardy` to `originx, originy, x, y` or something like that. Not sure what the best syntax would be

Comment: Nothing to add since the solution works perfectly and it is easy to understand it. Very nice answer. Thanks! And definetly a function to be implemented in `ggplot2` extension as mentioned by @r2evans

Comment: @MrFlick, clearly "naming variables" is a hard thing to do ... I tend to prefer self-declarative names, so even `originx, throughx` could work as well, but that's just a preference ... and `throughx`-vs-`towardx` is mostly a matter of preference. It might be interesting to have a `length=` aesthetic as well, where the default may be `Inf` (off-canvas) but it could easily be desired to have equidistant rays without needing to determine the endpoint. It's just _trig_ ;-)