# ggplot2: Reading maximum bar height from plot object containing geom_histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Like this [previous poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611691/relative-positioning-of-geom-text-in-ggplot2), I am also using `geom_text` to annotate plots in gglot2. And I want to position those annotations in relative coordinates (proportion of facet H & W) rather than data coordinates.  Easy enough for most plots, but in my case I'm dealing with histograms. I'm sure the relevant information as to the y scale must be lurking in the plot object somewhere (after adding `geom_histogram`), but I don't see where.

My question: How do I read maximum bar height from a faceted ggplot2 object containing `geom_histogram`? Can anyone help?

Comment: You mean maximum bar height in data coordinates or in relative coordinates against the facet height?

Comment: Well, when I typed it I meant data coordinates. I could use that plus the expansion factor to get what I need to position the text geom. Is there a better way?

Comment: If you want to make annotations at the top of bar in each facet, see my answer. Otherwise, could you please make things more clear, especially what you want to do finally?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I am wanting to annotate much like you show and your answer led me to what I needed. See comment below your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(plyr)
library(scales)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg)) + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..)) + facet_wrap(~am)
r <- print(p)
# in data coordinate
(dc <- dlply(r$data[[1]], .(PANEL), function(x) max(x$density)))
(mx <- dlply(r$data[[1]], .(PANEL), function(x) x[which.max(x$density), ]$x))

# add annotation (see figure below)
p + geom_text(aes(x, y, label = text), 
  data = data.frame(x = unlist(mx), y = unlist(dc), text = LETTERS[1:2], am = 0:1),
  colour = "red", vjust = 0)


# scale range
(yr <- llply(r$panel$ranges, "[[", "y.range"))
# in relative coordinates
(rc <- mapply(function(d, y) rescale(d, from = y), dc, yr))
```

[image]

Comment: One piece I was missing was this (r <- print(p1)). Given that, I can do r$panel$ranges[[1]]$y.range

Comment: Oops. Got distracted: One piece I was missing was this (r <- print(p1)). Given that, I can do (r$panel$ranges[[1]]$y.range) to get the yrange. I don't quite understand the ddply calls in your code (haven't worked with plyr much), but I'll play with it later. Do you see any obvious problem with directly accessing the y.range as I did here?

Comment: If each facet has different y-range, then you need to get it for each facet. `r$panel$ranges[[1]]$y.range` only returns that of first facet.

Comment: Understood. I'm using fixed scales. Thanks!

Comment: I can't see ranges  or panels inside the ggplot object. I am not using facets. Is the solution different if there are no facets? @kohske

Comment: I tried to replicate the plot using ggplot2 3.4.4. and this solution does not seem to work anymore.

Comment: This worked for me: https://community.rstudio.com/t/geom-histogram-max-bin-height/10026/2