# ggplot2: suppress drawing of plot when calling print method

Tags: r, printing, ggplot2

As a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828125/ggplot2-reading-maximum-bar-height-from-plot-object-containing-geom-histogram), suppose I do something like this:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg)) + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count..)) + facet_wrap(~am)
r <- print(p)
```

In the second line I'm calling the print method just so that I can programmatically inspect its return value before adding additional layers to the plot object.

My question: Is there a way to suppress drawing the plot at that point?

Comment: Why not just look at p then.  Why reassign to r?

Comment: @TylerRinker `p` and `r` end up being quite different objects. Use `str(p)` and `str(r)` etc. or click through to the linked question to see why ;)

Comment: Oh wow definitely very different.

Comment: That's right. r contains the info I need. See the linked question for details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look inside `ggplot2:::print.ggplot` you'll discover that what you probably want to use is either `ggplot_build()` or `ggplot_gtable()`, depending on what information you want to inspect.

`ggplot_build` returns the data object that is invisibly returned by ggplot2's print method, so that's probably what you're after. `ggplot_gtable` returns the grobs themselves, which allows for direct modification of the grid graphics objects themselves.

Comment: ggplot_build is jus the ticket. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
#Create a temporary plot file
png('TMP_PLOT')

#Inspect return value of plot

#When you're done
dev.off()
#Delete the plot you just generated
unlink('TMP_PLOT')
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having a plot window pop up at all. If I understand your suggestion, you are saying to send the plot to file rather than to a graphics device, and then delete the file. Is that right? I guess that would serve the purpose, but it seems less elegant than simply not creating the plot to begin with.

Comment: @DaveBraze This isn't necessary. See my answer.